# Remove Android Styling from ↩ Character

Tags: android, html, css, ascii

Is it possible to remove the default Android styling from the ↩ character. This is how I've styled it on my page:

[image]

This is how it looks on an Android (S4 Galaxy):

[image]

Is there some CSS to remove this default styling?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's Android doing that? What code produces that...

Comment: `<a href="#fnref:1" class="">↩</a>` That is what's rendering the reversed footnote icon.

Comment: It sounds like an emoji thing, I guess you'll have to use an image if you wish it to look the same cross platforms.

Comment: Yeah...feels like a font issue. Can't think that **Android** would do that by itself...perhaps the stock browser not the OS.

Comment: @sdcr Yeah, I thought it might be an emoji issue. It looks like one.